# not returning correct values when trying to shift and place elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

In my program the user determines the size on an array, then the user inputs values that are stored in descending order in the array as 'high scores'. The user then gets the option to update values in the array, although for my function which performs this task (insertScore) it doesnt print out the right values.

If:

1. 240
2. 110
3. 50

is stored, and the user decides to update the values, by inserting 150, the array should update to be

1. 240
2. 150
3. 110

and 50 will be removed, although for some reason when i run my code i keep getting '[Ljava.lang.Integer;@55f96302'? I have no idea why this is happening, and I have searched everywhere to find a way to fix this although i cant seem to find anyone else who has had that problem...

I know my error is mainly persisting in the insertScore function, but i cant find a reason why?

this is my code, thanks for any and all help:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighScores {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many values would you like to set the High Score list too?:");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        Integer[] zeroSet = {};
        Integer[] setScores = intialisingHighScores(userInput, zeroSet);
        System.out.println("Now Enter the high scores you wish to display:");
        Integer[] highScores = printHighScores(setScores, userInput);
        System.out.println("The high scores are:");
        for (int i=0; i<=(userInput-1); i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + highScores[i]);
        }
        while (userInput > 0){
            setScores = insertScore(userInput, setScores);
        }
    }
    public static Integer[] intialisingHighScores(int userInput, Integer[] zeroSet){
        zeroSet = new Integer [userInput];
        for (int index=0; index<=(userInput-1); index++){
            zeroSet[index] = 0;
        }
        return zeroSet;
    }
    public static Integer[] printHighScores(Integer[] setScores, int userInput) {
        Scanner inputNo = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i<=(userInput-1); i++){
            int scores = inputNo.nextInt();
            if(scores<0){
                System.out.println("No player can be that bad, please enter positive high scores only");
                scores = inputNo.nextInt();
                setScores[i] = scores;
            }
            else{
                setScores[i] = scores;
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(setScores, Collections.reverseOrder());
        return setScores;
    }
    public static int higherThan(Integer[] setScores){
        Scanner inputNo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter any updated scores");
        int newScore = inputNo.nextInt();
        return newScore;
    }
    public static Integer[] insertScore(int userInput, Integer[] setScores){
        int newScore = higherThan(setScores);
        for (int i=0; i<=(userInput-1); i++){
            if(setScores[i] < newScore ){
                for (int n=(userInput-2); n>i; n--){
                    setScores[n+1] = setScores[n];
                }
                setScores[i] = newScore;
                for(int loop=0; loop<=(userInput-1); loop++){
                    System.out.println(setScores);
                }
            }
        }
        return setScores;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the array directly which uses the toString and gives you **className@hashCode**.

As you are looping thru the list you might want to use the following:

```
public static Integer[] insertScore(int userInput, Integer[] setScores){
    int newScore = higherThan(setScores);
    for (int i=0; i<=(userInput-1); i++){
        if(setScores[i] < newScore ){
            for (int n=(userInput-2); n>i; n--){
                setScores[n+1] = setScores[n];
            }
            setScores[i] = newScore;
            for(int loop=0; loop<=(userInput-1); loop++){
                System.out.println(setScores[loop]); //***EDITED***//
            }
        }
    }
    return setScores;   
}
```

Comment: ah thank you, im such an idiot for not noticing that!

Comment: No sweat :) happens all the time.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `System.out.println(setScores);`, you're calling the `toString` method of an array. By default, [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) returns a String formatted as `class name @ hex hashcode`. If you want a more readable representation of the array, use [`Arrays#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(setScores));
```